# Refresh token revocation after it was expired

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, openiddict

I have a problem with revocation of "refresh token" after it was expired. I have a standard table "OpenIddict Tokens" where openiddict stores tokens. In Startup class where I configure OpenIddict, I setted:

```
.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) // It is just for check revocation of token
```

Immediately after receiving the tokens from `/connect/token` I try to refresh my tokens. I got "The specified refresh token is no longer valid" error and I noticed that in the database there is still a note about the expired refresh token.

Should it have stayed there or should be removed from database?

Answer (score 0):

Only `access token` could be refreshed using `refresh token`. On practice, refresh token is long-lived, as it represents the authorization granted to the client by the resource owner. And expired/blacklisted refresh token means that client access was revoked.

In other words, if the client has expired refresh token, it must do authentication again and receive a new pair of access/refresh tokens to access the resources.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Tell me please, how can I remove a row with invalid token from OpenIddictTokens table?
Should I do this by my own? Or this is job of OpenIddict?

Comment: @syler try to use built-in [OpenIddictTokenManager.RevokeAsync method](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/136#issuecomment-225068490). And the access tokens are not stored in the database.